# Scrolling Vertically with Angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

These questions are related to the [ScrollView](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/scrollview/#toc-scrollview-overview) component

I am able to scroll only horizontally.  Can we modify the scrollview to allow scrolling vertically?

Currently Kendo scrollview scrolls a whole page, for example, if the user scrolls a small portion of page then it scrolls back to fit the whole page again.  Can we disable this behavior?  I also would like a Vertical scroll component that should respond to the user pan and drag gestures

We are currently using currently:

- Kendo UI   : (2016 R3)
- Kendo UI (charts) : "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^0.10.3",
- Angular 2:    "@angular/core": "2.2.4",

Thanks for your help on this

Answer (score 1):

Currently none of these features are supported. You can [log missing features on UserVoice](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-2-feedback/category/181393-grid), so that you'll be updated on the planning and implementation status.

Answer (score -1):

you can set:

```
[width]="80"
```

in every kendo-grid-column.